# In django models for mysql, do we lose information when using IntegerField for int(1)

Tags: mysql, django

We have a mysql DB table that has attributes like:

```
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default           |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| age                   | int(1)           | YES  |     | NULL              |
| blah                  | int(1)           | YES  |     | NULL              |
```

I was curious about the int(1), and so referred to the docs, and here is a description:

```
M indicates the maximum display width for integer types. 
The maximum legal display width is 255. Display width is 
unrelated to the range of values a type can contain
[ . . . ]
```

Given that I want to preserve the current schema, is there a way in Django where we can specify display length of the `models.*IntegerField`?

app/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Grade(models.Model):
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the generated SQL:

```
>  python manage.py sql app

BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `app_grade` (
    `type` smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

**Edit**: I came to know of the command `manage.py inspectdb` that will generate model based on db tables present. For the table in question, the output for the column of type `int(1)` is:

```
class table(models.Model):
    [ . . . ]
    columnx = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='columnX', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    [ . . . ]
```

So django considers `int(M)` and `IntegerField` the same. I am fine with it as long as no information/constraint is lost. What are the recommendations here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the MySQL docs said, an `INT` is an `INT`. The display width doesn't affect the range of values that can be stored in the column or impose any other limitation on the values, so you don't need to take it into account. Display width for integer types really just affects *display* (and only for the limited set of things that actually respect it).

Now, the SQL that Django generated when you were using a `SmallIntegerField` used `SMALLINT`. `SMALLINT` *does* have a different (smaller) range of possible values than `INT`.

What's important here is that you preserve the data type, so use `IntegerField`.

Comment: got it. I also noticed that django doesn't define a `TinyIntField`. so if I have a column of type `tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill`, django stills outputs `IntegerField` for it. The spec here is important to mysql, but not so much for django model api. so how would i enforce the constraints in the model definition? i guess i could use `BooleanField`...let me look into it.

Comment: If your existing data model is using `tinyint` to represent boolean data, which is pretty common with MySQL, then `BooleanField` is probably the way to go.